# NMinimize::nnum: The function value [...] is not a number at [...]

Tags: mathematical-optimization, syntax

I have been trying to minimize a function, but I believe a syntax error is blocking the evaluation. I tried to add `NumericQ` to trigger the evaluation of the probability vector `p`, but the piecewise cost function (trivially defined here) does not evaluate to a number and I don't know why.

This code is reproducible, albite clunky as I wanted to preserve the (now useless) variables defined as closely as possible to my actual syntax.

```
Reproduce[v_: {{1,1},{1,2},{2,1},{2,2}},targeted_:{0.8,0.2}]:=
Module[{g,m,n,mse,piecewiseMSE, num,objective},
g = Length[First[v]];
m = Length[targeted];
n = Length[v];
mse[p__?NumericQ] :=Total[p];
piecewiseMSE[p__?NumericQ] :=Piecewise[{
 {10^9, p \[VectorLessEqual] ConstantArray[0,g]},
 {10^9, p \[VectorGreaterEqual] ConstantArray[1,g]}
 }, mse[p] ];

objective[p_?NumericQ]:= piecewiseMSE[p];
 NMinimize[objective[p],  p \[Element] Vectors[g,Reals]]
]
Reproduce[]
```

It produces an error `NMinimize::nnum: The function value piecewiseMSE$92320[{0.918621,0.716689}] is not a number at {Subscript[p, 1],Subscript[p, 2]} = {0.918621,0.716689}.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`VectorQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorQ.html) with the second argument [`NumericQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html):

```
Reproduce[v_ : {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}, 
   targeted_ : {0.8, 0.2}] := 
  Module[{g, m, n, mse, piecewiseMSE, num, objective}, 
   g = Length[First[v]];
   m = Length[targeted];
   n = Length[v];
   mse[p_ /; VectorQ[p, NumericQ]] := Total[p];
   piecewiseMSE[p_ /; VectorQ[p, NumericQ]] := 
    Piecewise[{{10^9, 
       p \[VectorLessEqual] ConstantArray[0, g]}, {10^9, 
       p \[VectorGreaterEqual] ConstantArray[1, g]}}, mse[p]];
   objective[p_ /; VectorQ[p, NumericQ]] := piecewiseMSE[p];
   NMinimize[objective[p], p \[Element] Vectors[g, Reals]]];
```